# Camera disable render for far objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity is there a way to stop the camera rendering few objects or lets say far away objects so that it is more performant? I can achieve this with adjusting the far-clipping plane. But I also want the objects to be seen by camera. Such that the objects are visible in the scene but not rendered by the camera? This is specifically for VR purpose. Is there a way to achieve such an unusual thing?

Comment: What do you mean "visible" not rendered?

Comment: @jiveturkey basically visible to the user but not rendered from the camera.

Comment: How do you think something that is not rendered by a camera is seen by the user? ....

Comment: I know what I am asking is unusual. I was just trying to see for performance reasons. Because the gameObjects should be visible as well as the camera should not lag. When I deactivate the far-away gameObjects, the performance increases and there is no lag in the camera.

Comment: But you want to see those far off gameObjects, right?  Have you done your occlusion culling yet?

Comment: @jiveturkey Yes I have used it. And still I am getting the lag.

Comment: another wacky idea is try another camera that renders where the other leaves off.  Ex: MainCamera from 0.01 to 500, SecondaryCamera from 500 to 1000.  Generally more Cameras are bad for performance but hey, first person shooters do it.  Maybe you can then adjust the second camera parameters to be more performant than the efirst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking for something to be visible but unrendered. This poses a conflicting problem, as rendering something is the process of making it visible.

Normally, you'd work with not rendering things outside of the viewport and LOD (level of detail).

### LOD

Basically rendering things far away with low level of detail, making the game more performant. You can see how to set it up here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LevelOfDetail.html

### Occlusion Culling

Culling is partly done by Unity, as can be read here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html

---

There might be more answers than this, I'm not sure I fully understand what you wish and I am not a game designer by profession so my optimization skills are sub-par.

Comment: Thanks your answer. You are right about the multiple ways, my aim is to have my game as performant as possible. I have already created occlusion culling in my game. I will take a look at LODs.